# Null poiter exception when deploying axis2 web service

Tags: jakarta-ee, apache-axis, tomcat7

I am currently starting out with developing a web service, using the eclipse IDE and axis 2 on a local tomcat 7.0 server.

When I try to deploy the service, I get:

```
[ERROR] The encoSendInterface service, which is not valid, caused The following error occurred during schema generation: null org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: The following error occurred during schema generation: null
at  org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:432)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.buildServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:101)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.ArchiveReader.processServiceGroup(ArchiveReader.java:178)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceDeployer.deploy(ServiceDeployer.java:82)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.DeploymentFileData.deploy(DeploymentFileData.java:136)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.doDeploy(DeploymentEngine.java:813)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.repository.util.WSInfoList.update(WSInfoList.java:144)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.update(RepositoryListener.java:377)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.RepositoryListener.checkServices(RepositoryListener.java:254)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentEngine.loadServices(DeploymentEngine.java:142)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.WarBasedAxisConfigurator.loadServices(WarBasedAxisConfigurator.java:283)
at org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContextFactory.createConfigurationContext(ConfigurationContextFactory.java:95)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.initConfigContext(AxisServlet.java:584)
at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.init(AxisServlet.java:454)
at org.apache.axis2.webapp.AxisAdminServlet.init(AxisAdminServlet.java:60)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1080)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5015)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5302)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
 Caused by: org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: The following error occurred during schema generation: null
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:396)
... 27 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.DefaultSchemaGenerator.generateSchema(DefaultSchemaGenerator.java:606)
at org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.DefaultSchemaGenerator.generateSchemaTypeforNameCommon(DefaultSchemaGenerator.java:1092)
at org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.DefaultSchemaGenerator.generateSchemaForType(DefaultSchemaGenerator.java:996)
at org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.DefaultSchemaGenerator.processMethods(DefaultSchemaGenerator.java:385)
at org.apache.axis2.description.java2wsdl.DefaultSchemaGenerator.generateSchema(DefaultSchemaGenerator.java:273)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.util.Utils.fillAxisService(Utils.java:468)
at org.apache.axis2.deployment.ServiceBuilder.populateService(ServiceBuilder.java:388)
... 27 more
[INFO] org.apache.axis2.deployment.DeploymentException: The following error occurred during schema generation: null
```

Is there any way to find out, what causes this exception?

The current version of my WS does not read any config files. Are there any libriries I cannot use, when building a web service, that could crash the whole show?

Regards,
LuigiEd

Comment: I have resolved the issue. One of the Ws's public methods had a parameter named exactly like one of the classes attributes. While that works in regular (javaSE) development, it does seem to cause trouble in a web service. When I removed the parameter, the serves deployed correctly. Can anyone explain this behaviour to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. One of the Ws's public methods had a parameter named exactly like one of the classes attributes. While that works in regular (javaSE) development, it does seem to cause trouble in a web service.

Answer (score 2):

In case this helps anyone, I solved this problem by adding `@WebMethod(exclude = true)` to some setters I had on the service class (for dependency injection).

According to [JAX-WS Guide](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/jaxws-guide.html)

> If the @WebMethod annotation is not specified, all public methods are
>   exposed including the inherited methods with the exception of methods
>   inherited from java.lang.Object. The exclude parameter of the
>   @WebMethod annotation can be used to control which methods are
>   exposed.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same (or very similar) issue after upgrading from axis2 1.5.1 to 1.6.2.

Adding '@WebMethod(exclude = true)' to non-webmethod public methods fixed it for me.